# Proof Verification: Baby Rudin Chapter 4 Exercise 6

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

If $f$ is defined on $E$, the graph of $f$ is the set of points $(x, f(x))$, for $x \in E$. Suppose $E$ is compact, and prove that $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if its graph is compact.

Hello! Can anyone check whether my proof to this problem is correct? Can I improve it in any way?

Because $f$ is continuous , $f(E)$ is compact. The set $E \times f(E)$ is compact as well. We show that $G = \{(x, f(x)) | x \in E\}$ is closed in $E \times f(E)$; its compactness will follow. Hence, let $(q,r)$ be a point in $G^\mathsf{c}$. Let $V_r$ and $V_{f(q)}$ be disjoint neighborhoods in $f(E)$ containing $r$ and $f(q)$, respectively. By the continuity of $f$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $q$ such that $f(U) \subset V_{f(q)}$. Because $f(x) \notin V_r$ for all $x \in U$, $U \times V_r$ is a neighborhood of $(q,r)$ contained in $G^c$.

Conversely, assume that $f$ is discontinuous at the point $q$. We show that there exists an open cover of $G$ that admits no finite subcover. Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $f(q)$ such that every neighborhood of $q$ contains a point whose image is outside of $V$. Construct a sequence of points $\{p_n\}$ such that  $p_n \in B(q,\frac{1}{n})$ and $f(p_n) \notin V$. Also, set $$U_n = \overline {B(q,\frac{1}{n})}^\mathsf{c}.$$  The collection $\{E \times V\} \cup \{U_n \times f(E)\}, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ covers $G$ because every point in $G$ is either equal to $(q, f(q))$ or has a first coordinate that lies outside $\overline {B(q,\frac{1}{n})}$ for some $n$. Every finite subcollection omits $(p_n, f(p_n))$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Looks fine to me, though you may want to specify that the open cover you are constructing is an open cover of $G$ in $E\times f(E)$

Comment: Alright. Thank you so much!